# Cartesian product in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, cartesian-product

I've been trying to do a function that returns the Cartesian Product of n sets,in Dr Scheme,the sets are given as a list of lists,I've been stuck at this all day,I would like a few guidelines as where to start.

----LATER EDIT -----

Here is the solution I came up with,I'm sure that it's not by far the most efficent or neat but I'm only studing Scheme for 3 weeks so be easy on me.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658229/scheme-lisp-nested-loops-and-recursion

Comment: yes ,it's part of homework,I don't necessarily need the code,I want some guidelines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  ;returs a list wich looks like ((nr l[0]) (nr l[1])......)
  (define cart-1(λ(l nr)
      (if (null? l) 
             l 
             (append (list (list nr (car l))) (cart-1 (cdr l) nr)))))

;Cartesian product for 2 lists
(define cart-2(λ(l1 l2)
                (if(null? l2) 
             '() 
             (append (cart-1 l1 (car l2)) (cart-2 l1 (cdr l2))))))

 ;flattens a list containg sublists
(define flatten
(λ(from)
 (cond [(null? from) from]
      [(list? (car from)) (append (flatten (car from)) (flatten (cdr from)))]
      [else (cons (car from) (flatten (cdr from)))])}) 

;applys flatten to every element of l
(define flat
(λ(l)
(if(null? l)
l
(cons (flatten (car l)) (flat (cdr l))))))

;computes Cartesian product for a list of lists by applying cart-2
(define cart
(lambda (liste aux)
 (if (null? liste)
  aux
  (cart (cdr liste) (cart-2 (car liste) aux)))))


(define (cart-n l) (flat (cart (cdr l ) (car l))))
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a concise implementation that is also designed to minimize the size of the resulting structure in memory, by sharing the tails of the component lists.  It uses SRFI-1.

```
(define (cartesian-product . lists)
  (fold-right (lambda (xs ys)
                (append-map (lambda (x)
                              (map (lambda (y)
                                     (cons x y))
                                   ys))
                            xs))
              '(())
              lists))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
;compute the list of the (x,y) for y in l
(define (pairs x l)
  (define (aux accu x l)
    (if (null? l)
        accu
        (let ((y (car l))
              (tail (cdr l)))
          (aux (cons (cons x y) accu) x tail))))
  (aux '() x l))

(define (cartesian-product l m)   
  (define (aux accu l)
    (if (null? l) 
        accu
        (let ((x (car l)) 
              (tail (cdr l)))
          (aux (append (pairs x m) accu) tail))))
  (aux '() l))
```

*Source: [Scheme/Lisp nested loops and recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658229/scheme-lisp-nested-loops-and-recursion/1658894#1658894)*

Comment: how is this supposed to help ?This is the Cartesian Product of 2 sets,my question was for n sets,I know how to compute it for two sets,I don't know how to make it for n

Comment: Combine the 2-set version with fold to get an n-set version. In general for associative operations, you can define an n argument version in terms of the 2 argument version with fold.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my first solution (suboptimal):

```
#lang scheme
(define (cartesian-product . lofl)
  (define (cartOf2 l1 l2)
    (foldl 
     (lambda (x res) 
       (append 
        (foldl 
         (lambda (y acc) (cons (cons x y) acc)) 
         '() l2) res))
     '() l1))
  (foldl cartOf2 (first lofl) (rest lofl)))

(cartesian-product '(1 2) '(3 4) '(5 6))
```

Basically you want to produce the product of the product of the lists.

Comment: Also if you look at the question that Yuval posted Paul Hollingsworth posted a well documented version, albeit not working in plt-scheme. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658229/scheme-lisp-nested-loops-and-recursion/1677386#1677386

Comment: Regarding the Cipher's solution, what can you do in order to get the list of lists undotted?

Comment: I think what you mean is that you don't want the result to be a list of improper lists (or nested pairs), rather you want a list of lists. If so, the easiest/simplest/worst way to accomplish this would be to change (cons x y) to (cons x (if (list? y) y (list y))). I don't like this. But its not my homework... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I tried my hand at making the elegant solution of Mark H Weaver (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20591545/7666) easier to understand.

```
import : srfi srfi-1
define : cartesian-product . lists
    define : product-of-two xs ys
         define : cons-on-each-ys x
            map : lambda (y) (cons x y)
                . ys
         append-map cons-on-each-ys
                  . xs
    fold-right product-of-two '(()) lists
```

It is still the same logic, but naming the operations.

The above is in [wisp-syntax](http://draketo.de/english/wisp) aka SRFI-119. The equivalent plain Scheme is:

```
(import (srfi srfi-1))
(define (cartesian-product . lists)
    (define (product-of-two xs ys)
         (define (cons-on-each-ys x)
            (map (lambda (y) (cons x y))
                ys))
         (append-map cons-on-each-ys
                  xs))
    (fold-right product-of-two '(()) lists))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my answer, I'm doing some homework. Using Guile on Emacs.

```
(define product                                                               
  (lambda (los1 los2)                                                         
    (if (or (null? los1) (null? los2))                                        
        '()                                                                   
        (cons (list (car los1) (car los2))                                    
              (append (product (list (car los1)) (cdr los2))                  
                    (product (cdr los1)  los2))))                             
                                                                              
        )                                                                     
    )                                                                         
                                                                              
(product '(a b c ) '(x y)) 

;; Result:
=> ((a x) (a y) (b x) (b y) (c x) (c y))
```