# Can any one convert this code to Pseudo Code

Tags: racket

```
#lang racket
(define (cartesian-product . lists)
(foldr (lambda (xs ys)
            (append-map (lambda (x)
                          (map (lambda (y)
                                 (cons x y))
                               ys))
                        xs))
          '(())
          lists))

(cartesian-product '(1 2 3) '(5 6))
```

I have racket lang code, that calculate cartesian product of two sets or lists, I don't understand the code well, can any one convert code to pseudo code.

Comment: Did you see Arne's answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485226/cartesian-product-in-scheme

Comment: @soegaard i did, there is no explanation there!!!, so I asked for any pseudo code thanks

Answer (score 1):

The function corresponds to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#n-ary_Cartesian_product) definition of cartesian products.

1. The dot `.` in the argument means that `lists` will collect all the arguments (in a list) no matter how many are passed in.
2. How to call such a function? Use `apply`. It applies a function using items from a list as the arguments: `(apply f (list x-1 ... x-n)) = (f x-1 ... x-n)`
3. foldr is just an abstraction over the natural recursion on lists

```
; my-foldr : [X Y] [X Y -> Y] Y [List-of X] -> Y
; applies fun from right to left to each item in lx and base
(define (my-foldr combine base lx)
  (cond [(empty? lx) base]
        [else (combine (first lx) (my-foldr func base (rest lx)))]))
```

Applying the simplifications from 1), 2) and 3) and turning the "combine" function in foldr to a separate helper:

```
(define (cartesian-product2 . lists)
  (cond [(empty? lists) '(())]
        [else (combine-cartesian (first lists)
                                 (apply cartesian-product2 (rest lists)))]))

(define (combine-cartesian fst cart-rst)
  (append-map (lambda (x)
                (map (lambda (y)
                       (cons x y))
                     cart-rst))
              fst))

(cartesian-product2 '(1 2 3) '(5 6))
```

Let's think about "what" `combine-cartesian` does: it simply converts a *n-1*-ary cartesian product to a *n*-ary cartesian product.

We want:

```
(cartesian-product '(1 2) '(3 4) '(5 6))
; = 
; '((1 3 5) (1 3 6) (1 4 5) (1 4 6) (2 3 5) (2 3 6) (2 4 5) (2 4 6))
```

We have `(first lists) = '(1 2)` and the result of the recursive call (induction):

```
(cartesian-product '(3 4) '(5 6))
; = 
; '((3 5) (3 6) (4 5) (4 6))
```

To go from what we have (result of the recursion) to what we want, we need to cons 1 onto every element, and cons 2 onto every element, and append those lists. Generalizing this, we get a simpler reformulation of the combine function using nested loops:

```
(define (combine-cartesian fst cart)
  (apply append
         (for/list ([elem-fst fst])
           (for/list ([elem-cart cart])
             (cons elem-fst elem-cart)))))
```

To add a dimension, we consed every element of `(first lists)` onto every element of the cartesian product of the rest.

*Pseudocode:*

```
  cartesian product <- takes in 0 or more lists to compute the set of all 
                       ordered pairs
    - cartesian product of no list is a list containing an empty list.
    - otherwise: take the cartesian product of all but one list
                 and add each element of that one list to every 
                 element of the cartesian product and put all 
                 those lists together.
```